# SQL запрос, группировка по дате?

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') as `date`, `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` 
WHERE `orders`.`status` = 1
AND `orders`.`date` >= '2016-09-08' AND `orders`.`date` <= ('2016-09-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY `orders`.`id`
ORDER BY `orders`.`date` DESC
```

Получаю такой результат:

```
date        id
----------  -------
11.09.2016  10051961
11.09.2016  10051962
11.09.2016  10051963
10.09.2016  10051895
10.09.2016  10051894
10.09.2016  10051897
10.09.2016  10051898
10.09.2016  10051894
09.09.2016  10051898
09.09.2016  10051890
08.09.2016  10051792
08.09.2016  10051789
```

Вопрос, как сгруппировать кол-во заказов по дням, то есть вида:

```
date        count
----------  -------
11.09.2016  3
10.09.2016  5
09.09.2016  2
08.09.2016  2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`, COUNT(`id`) AS `count` 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE `orders`.`status` = 1
  AND `orders`.`date` >= '2016-09-08' AND `orders`.`date` <= ('2016-09-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y')
ORDER BY `orders`.`date` DESC
```

Comment: при таком варианте, получается кол-во товаров внутри заказа.

Comment: @XenK уточните тогда структуру вашей таблицы, откуда вы выбираете данные

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте это:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("host", "user", "pass", "db");

$items = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`orders`.`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') as `date`, `orders`.`id` FROM `orders` WHERE `orders`.`status` = 1 AND `orders`.`date` >= '2016-09-08' AND `orders`.`date` <= ('2016-09-11' + INTERVAL 1 DAY) GROUP BY `orders`.`id` ORDER BY `orders`.`date` DESC");

while($fetch = $query->fetch_array) {
    $items[$fetch["date"]]++;
}

print_r($items);
?>
```